# How to enable a module for custom theme and keep it disable for other theme or luma theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, module-development

I have a module in the vendor folder installed via Composer. I want to keep it enabled for my custom theme. But when a user selects the Luma theme, this module should be disabled.

My module depends on a theme, so it throws errors when I enable Luma.
How can I handle this in Magento 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

> **Add the below code to your module to check which is the current theme. and you can add conditions where specific to your theme then only your code is work**

```
protected $themeProvider;

protected $scopeConfig;

protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProviderInterface $themeProvider,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->themeProvider = $themeProvider;
}

public function getCurentThemeData(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $themeId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::XML_PATH_THEME_ID,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    );

    return $this->themeProvider->getThemeById($themeId);
}
```

**In Phtml file**

```
$themeData = $block->getCurentThemeData();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($themeData->getData());
echo "</pre>";

if ($themeData->getCode() == 'YourThemeCode') {
    // code...
}
```